# Problem with validation in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes, metadata

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace Entities.EntityExtensions
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(IncomeDeclaration_Validation))]
    public partial class IncomeDeclaration
    {
    }

    [Bind(Exclude="Id")]
    public class IncomeDeclaration_Validation
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

"Im getting a the type or namespace Bind is not defined" error... Im lost.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included `System.Web.Mvc` namespace there...

Comment: Hmm, thats because Im using the POCO templates generator and I placed the poco generated classes in a different project... should the Validation Buddy class be placed in the Web project?? does that even make sense?

Comment: BindAttribute is defined in System.Web.Mvc namespace.. so you will need to include that..